# Using Leibniz formula to calculate pi without importing anything

Tags: python

So I am trying to approximate pi using Leibniz formula.  I atleast want to approximate to .5 and .1.  Also, when my approximation becomes larger than the precision value, I finish the loop.  This is what I have so far, but I can not get my precision down to .5 or .1 due to the range restriction, can anyone help?

```
def pi(precision):

    ans = 0;
    while (ans <= precision ):

        for k in range(0, precision + precision + 1):
            ans = ans + ((4.0 * (-1)**k) / (2*k + 1))




    return ans
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks pretty good. Notice though that you use precision in your range. For one thing, range can only take in integer values, thus precision must be an integer. You might have mistaken precision for number of terms in the leibniz sum. If so, your function would look like the following:

```
def pi(terms):
    ans = 0
    for k in range(0, terms):
        ans += ((4.0 * (-1)**k) / (2*k + 1))
    return ans
```

Output:

```
pi(100000) = 3.1415826535897198
```

If you want to actually use precision, you could use a while loop and have it break when the absolute value of your "old estimate" minus your "new estimate" is less than the precision value (often called the tolerance level). Here is some code that would work:

```
def pi(precision):
    k=0
    new_estimate = 0
    while True:
        old_estimate = new_estimate
        new_estimate = old_estimate + ((4.0 * (-1)**k) / (2*k + 1))
        k+=1
        if abs(old_estimate - new_estimate) < precision:
            break
    return new_estimate
```

Output:

```
pi(.00001) = 3.141597653564762
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Leibniz's formula converges extremely slowly. With your program  having 3.14157 using 100000 iterations

Unfortunately the range() function doesn't support the float type.  You can easily implement it with a function for example using float

```
def frange(start, stop, step):
  i = start
  while i < stop:
    yield i
    i += step

for i in frange(0.5, 1.0, 0.1):
  print(i)
```

Just adapt frange at your program and you could increase the precision